# How happily will taxis cross the triple-point borders around Basel?

Tags: france, germany, switzerland, taxis, basel

I am looking at travelling to Basel, Switzerland early next week (Tuesday). It would appear that hotels are very hard to come by at a reasonable price, so I am looking at staying in Mulhouse in nearby France. It seems that a taxi journey between there and the part of Basel I want to visit (in Swiss Basel) is only half an hour. However, how easy will I find it to get taxis across the border in either direction (potentially around 6am or 10pm)? Are there any immigration formalities at all, or does the Schengen zone mean we'll be able to cross freely? I vaguely remember customs posts from a previous visit. Is the same true of German Basel and Swiss Basel?

*Update*: even if there are no immigration formalities, will taxi companies be happy to cross the border?

Comment: @pnuts The Swiss side of the border post (towards Basel) is *definitely* manned. The French side (towards France) is sometimes manned. *Never* assume that custom officers won't be there. ;)

Comment: @JoErNanO Switzerland is part of Schengen, so I am surprised they still have manned border stations

Comment: @Andrew It doesn't answer your question, but Basel has some decent bed and breakfasts through booking.com and airbnb

Comment: A good question.  With the by now rhetorical question: what about the trains?

Comment: @GayotFow I'm not considering trains right now because that still requires getting a taxi at each end - I'm going to be travelling early in the morning, late at night, and cost is not an issue. But it's a good thought.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier, I don't know the answer, but a useful phrase if you are searching in German is "Dreiländereck Taxigesetz" (roughly three country corner taxi rules)

Comment: I am pretty sure taxis only cross one border at a time. The triple-point is in the middle of the Rhine river!

Comment: But remember to consider the price. If the Hotel on Mulhouse is cheaper but the difference is lower than the taxi fee, your idea will not be effective.

Comment: @Matteo, hotels in Basel are going for > €500. So I don't think there's any danger of that!

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Not sure about what you need but you can find a lot of nice *** Hotels for much lower prices in Basel

Comment: Unfortunately my hotel choice is restricted to a corporate-approved travel list.

Comment: @Matteo I believe this was during Baselworld or very close to that. Even if you ignore price, just finding availabilities during Baselworld used to be near impossible. Staying in Mulhouse, Zurich or Bern was quite common, and many hotels there actually had shuttles going to the fair. Not sure how things work out nowadays with the decline of Baselworld and the effects of the pandemic. As soon as the event is over things go back to normal.

Answer (score 10):

I've taken taxis from the Basel EuroAirport (which is in France) from both the French side and the Swiss side of the airport to my home in Germany.

The French taxis drive straight east across France into Germany.

The Swiss taxis go south through Basel, then back north again to Germany, which means a longer and more expensive ride, as if the Swiss taxi rates weren't high enough already.  This is because the French and Swiss sides of the airport are separated outside (though you can cross inside the airport), so the Swiss taxis have to follow the customs road to Basel.  You can read more about this here: [May a cyclist or a pedestrian cross from Switzerland to France near the Basel EuroAirport without going into the airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161805)

So they will all get you to Germany with no problem, but Swiss taxis will take a longer and pricier route.

However, I would also point out that Swiss public transit is excellent and worth considering.  Bus 50 can take you from the EuroAirport to Basel SBB, the main train station and transit hub in Basel.  From there you can get basically anywhere by public transit.

Public transit may even be covered in your hotel stay.  I don't know about France, but many hotels in Switzerland and Germany include travel cards that provide you with free travel in a large area.  Sometimes the hotel or the city you're staying in can give you a temporary pass (which you print) to get from airport to hotel for free.  It's worth asking.

Comment: The op asked for transportation between Mulhouse and Basel. Your text deosn't answer his question at all.

Comment: @NicolasB 1. Check the title of the question.  2. Check sentences like these: "However, how easy will I find it to get taxis across the border in either direction?"  My answer did focus on Germany more than France, but the border-crossing and public-transit aspects are applicable in either case.

Answer (score 8):

To add to the answer of @andra. I looked at the websites of the [taxi companies of Basel](https://www.basel.com/en/taxis-basel). While again, there is no explicit mention of it, one of the [companies](http://www.enzotaxi.ch/en/) specifically states as their motto:

> Der Shuttle Dienst im Dreiländereck Schweiz, Frankreich & Deutschland

This translates to "The shuttle service in the triple-point Switzerland, France and Germany". Furthermore they have an online booking request feature, which seems to accept both German and French places when I tried it and give a valid price. (To be fair, they seem to accept about any place that google maps can route to, so maybe you better send them a request first).

Based on that I would agree with the other answers, that it shouldn't be a problem to get taxis to drive over the border.

On a different note, I strongly recommend you to book a taxi by phone, as just hailing a taxi is not very common in Switzerland, even less so if you are outside of the city centre. Furthermore as you will be going there during the period when Basel World is taking place, it might be quite difficult to get a taxi in the first place. (I guess that is also the reason you can't find a room in Basel).

Comment: I tried the point to point fare search too and I do agree that the tool seems to accept any place indexed on Google maps.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up about Basel World, that explains a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: I have never took a taxi from France/Germany to/from Basel.

It seems to be possible. On [tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g188049-i752-k6415791-Cost_of_taxi_Basel_to_Mulhouse-Basel.html) it is mentioned that you should expect a cost of CHF 150. Also the [wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Basel) entry on Basel mentions a museum in Germany which is reachable by taxi:

> Vitra Design Museum, Charles-Eames-Str. 1, Weil am Rhein, Germany, +49
>   7621 702 3200. No collection, only changing temporary exhibitions -
>   see website [26]. But worth the visit for any self-respecting
>   architecture junkie: During a guided tour of the campus (Tuesday -
>   Sunday, at 12PM and 2PM, 2 hours, call ahead), see Frank Gehry's first
>   European building, and more structures by Zaha Hadid, Tadao Ando,
>   Nicholas Grimshaw and Alvaro Siza. Bring your passport and take bus
>   no. 55 from Claraplatz or Basel's Badischer Bahnhof to the stop
>   "Vitra" in Weil am Rhein (15 - 20 minutes). You can also take the
>   train to the trainstation Weil am Rhein. From there schedule a
>   15-minute walk to the museum. - **Or take a taxi from downtown Basel (15
>   minutes).**

Based on these two internet pages, I assume that taxi's regularly cross borders.

Comment: If the taxi driver is collecting CHF150 or more for a 30mn drive, then the answer to the question in the title is certainly "very happily".

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't figure out with a decent bit of certainty if taxis do indeed cross the Swiss/French border in Basel happily. All the websites point to taxi services to and from the Euro Airport, and [these seem to be split between the French and Swiss sides of the arrival exits](http://www.euroairport.com/en/passengers/access/taxi.html). You can try calling any of the French taxi services listed to check if they do indeed cross into Switzerland.

Just to add a different option, if taxis won't take you across the border, I'm prepared to bet that you'll find a car-sharing frontalier traveling the Mulhouse-Basel route willing to take you onboard. Provided you are legally allowed to immigrate Switzerland, of course. [See here for the results from a sample search on blablacar.](http://m.covoiturage.fr/trajets/mulhouse/bale/#?fn=Mulhouse&fc=47.750839%7C7.335888&fcc=FR&tn=B%C3%A2le%2C+Suisse&tc=47.567442%7C7.597551&tcc=CH&sort=trip_date&order=asc&limit=10&page=1)

For completeness sake note that whilst there might be no immigration controls, Switzerland does enforce customs checks. The Swiss post on the way to Basel is definitely manned. Switzerland is inside Schengen but outside the Customs Union and therefore performs it's own customs controls at the border.  On your way out of Switzerland however the border post is often empty on both sides, especially during peak hour when all the frontaliers go home. This is all based on personal experience. I've been going through the Basel border roughly every two months, in both directions and at all times of the day (including peak hour yesterday evening).